# How to submit multiple files with the same POST name with requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-post, python-requests, multipartform-data

With `requests`, when using POST with simple data, I can use the same name for multiple values. The CURL command:

```
curl --data "source=contents1&source=contents2" example.com
```

can be translated to:

```
data = {'source': ['contents1', 'contents2']}
requests.post('example.com', data)
```

The same doesn't work with files. If I translate the working CURL command:

```
curl --form "source=@./file1.txt" --form "source=@./file2.txt" example.com
```

to:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:
    files = {'source': [f1, f2]}
    requests.post('example.com', files=files)
```

only the last file is received.

`MultiDict` from `werkzeug.datastructures` doesn't help either.

How to submit multiple files with the same POST name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use a dictionary, use a list of tuples; each tuple a `(name, file)` pair:

```
files = [('source', f1), ('source', f2)]
```

The `file` element can be another tuple with more detail about the file; to include a filename and the mimetype, you can do:

```
files = [
    ('source', ('f1.ext', f1, 'application/x-example-mimetype'),
    ('source', ('f2.ext', f2, 'application/x-example-mimetype'),
]
```

This is documented in the [*POST Multiple Multipart-Encoded Files* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) of the *Advanced Usage* chapter of the documentation.